# Returning big size byte array or using ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, arrays, outputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

My question is with big size byte array (from 10k bytes), should I return direct the byte array value like this:

```
byte[] my_function() {
...
return value;
}
```

or use ByteArrayOutputStream/OutputStream as an param?

```
void my_function(ByteArrayOutputStream os) {
...
os.write(value);
}
```

Could you show me the advantage of using ByteArrayOutputStream/OutputStream against returning the result direct?

Comment: `ByteArrayOutputStream`? None. Plain `OutputStream` would leave the option to the caller of the function to use any other type of stream including, but not limited to, files, network, byte[],...

Comment: I updated my question, I just want to understand better behaviors of the program. Maybe they have some differences in terms of program memory,etc? Thanks, (my question seems to be very stupid @_@)

Comment: I don't really have much to add. Taking an `OutputStream` as parameter gives the people using your function much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment of njzk2:

Plain OutputStream would leave the option to the caller of the function to use any other type of stream including, but not limited to, files, network, byte[],..
Taking an OutputStream as parameter gives the people using your function much more flexibility